# tomcat hot modified spring parameters

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

I have a spring application with DAO layer and in my database I have a table in it I put application properties. My application is ruing on Tomcat web server.
Is there a method to take into account the modification of the spring properties that I did, directly from the database without restart tomcat!

think's!

Comment: I don't know of any way to automatically update property values at runtime using Spring.  If you are injecting these property values using Spring, my understanding is that this is done at initialization time, and the running app would have to handle updating at runtime.  You would have to come up with some method to set the values at runtime.  The biggest challenge would be making it thread-safe.  Perhaps, instead of injecting the values, you should have the application read them from the DB each time it needs them.

Comment: Recovering parameters from the database is going very well, but for every change I must restartTomcat to take into account modifications.
What I'm looking for is a way to do a tomcat hot deploy.

Comment: If you are changing things about Tomcat, I think the only option would be to run Tomcat embedded.  This way you can change the properties in Tomcat and possibly restart it internally.  I would think there are things that can be changed, like max threads, that would be changeable at runtime, but things like listening address/port that would require restarting the daemon.  If you ran the daemon embedded, you could do all of that internal.